# Issues with the new Entity Framework (June 2011 CTP causing unknown errors)

Tags: entity-framework

So I installed Entity Framework June CTP day before and all was fine until I went to add POCO's to the EF, that's when I got this error

[image]

So I thought to myself 'It must have been the CTP that's causing this, so I went and unloaded it. I restarted Visual Studio and was greeted with this message:

[image]

I hit No and Visual Studio finished loading my project. When I once again tried to add the POCO's I was greeted with this error:

[image]

So does anyone know what's going on and how I can resolve this issue? I know Entity Framework 4.2 has new items but for the time being I prefer the POCO way of doing things.

Comment: What does unloaded mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF CTP 2011 is very first preview of EF 4.2. It also shows only subset of features expected in EF 4.2. First of all it is not for developing production code and it should not be installed on the machine where you write a production EF code.

It is expected that CTP can contain bugs - that is why CTPs are published - to collect feedback and find bugs. It is not clear what you actually did to get the error but if you have a technical problem with CTP ask on [EF pre-release](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adonetefx/threads) forum for help.

Comment: "it should not be installed on the machine where you write a production EF code"...to release code to the public that's so unstable that it can corrupt your machine...that's just unacceptable. It's not ready to be a CTP at that point.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply remove EF 4.2 ? Removal guide here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/06/30/announcing-the-microsoft-entity-framework-june-2011-ctp.aspx

Comment: I tried that and it caused even more errors, so it seems I'm stuck with it and need to figure out how to make it play nice

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly same problem and resolved it by uninstalling "SQL Server Tools for Data Framework June 2011 CTP" - download it at http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26660, run and select the Remove option.

After that I was able to recover the Entity Framework tools to SP1 state using the steps in Uninstall section described at
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/06/30/announcing-the-microsoft-entity-framework-june-2011-ctp.aspx.

Comment: I had to manually remove the CTP's binding redirect policy file (via `gacutil /u policy.4.0.system.data.entity`) after uninstalling the SQL Server Tools to get rid of the System.Data.Entity error.